# Ejercicio de lista de numeros terminados en 2 con un fallo desconocido

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio en el que he estado trabajando y resulta que, aunque me da todos los resultados que le pido, arroja una excepción de ArrayOutOfBounds (on índices fuera de rango). ¿Alguno ve el fallo y me corrige por favor?
Muchas gracias

```
package ejerciciosGenerales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejer5 {
// Leer un numeroS y contar cuantoS acaban en 2
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Introduzca el total de numeros que desea ingresar: ");

    int todosNumeros = scn.nextInt();

    int[] numeros = new int[todosNumeros];

    System.out.println("Introduzca " + todosNumeros + " numeros: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Numero " + (i + 1) + ": ");

        numeros[i] = scn.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Los numeros introducidos son: ");

    try {
        for (int i = 0; 1 < numeros.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(numeros[i]);

        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
exc.printStackTrace();

    }

    System.out.println("Y los numeros acabados en 2 son: ");
    for (int i = 0; 1 < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] % 10 == 2) {

            System.out.println(numeros[i]);

        }

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso se debe a que tienes que comparar en el bucle el valor de `i` y no el valor de 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(numeros[i]);
}
```

Comment: meca, claro hahah vaya chorrada xD ( te daria upvote pero cubrí el cupo hoy :( mañana lo hago ^^ )

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por ayudarme!

Comment: @MikeWazowKN De nada! ^^

Comment: @MikeWazowKN recuerda marcar como valida la respuesta si te ha resuelto el problema :D ambos ganaréis reputacion

Answer (score 3):

Si en los bucles for pones como condición el número 1, siempres se va a cumplir así que el bucle saltará cuando la variable i llegue al final del array creado.

```
for (int i = 0; **1** < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numeros[i]);
        }
```

Deberias cambiar 1 por i o una variable que sea dinámica y se ajuste al tamaño del array.

Espero sea de ayuda! :)

Comment: Estupendo, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Está bien que quieras participar mucho, ya que eres nuevo. pero es una respuesta identica a la ya dada por @error404 y no aportas nada nuevo ... intenta contestar preguntas sin respuestas o no repetirlas ^^'

Comment: @lois6b gracias por tu comentario pero la diferencia de 4 minutos entre una respuesta y otra es el tiempo que me ha costado entrar en la pregunta, identificar el problema y escribir la respuesta por lo que no sabía que otra respuesta había sido escrita.

Comment: Sin problema, pues ^^ un saludo